# Who's he? vs What is he? when the answer is "He is an English footballer."

Tags: expressions

Who's he? vs What is he? when the answer is "He is an English footballer."

Firstly, I thought it's "Who is he?" simply because "-What's he? -He is an English footballer." doesn't sound comfortable with me. And I can't remember this "What" question can lead to information like nationality (very likely my lack of knowledge and hence I'm here).

And then I found another post on this site saying:
Normally, "Who is he?" asks a person's name, or possibly his position or occupation. "Who is he?" "He's Joe. He's a cop." "What is he?" asks chiefly for a person's nature, position, or occupation, not his name. "What is he?" "He's a cop [as opposed to a soldier or fireman, say]" or "He's the commander of the submarine" or "He [Spock] is a Vulcan." There is some overlap with those questions.

Which makes me feel that an answer other than a "name" seems really less likely to be the answer of "Who is he?"

Any insights? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing not addressed at the proposed duplicate question: There could be times that "Who" is really asking for an explanation of an individual's significance, not just their signifier. When the Lone Ranger rides through and the townspeople ask "Who was that masked man," they're really looking for more than "John Reid." When Inigo Montoya inquires of the Man In Black, "Who *are* you," the name "Wesley" would mean nothing to him. His question is a placeholder for "What kind of backstory explains the individual I'm faced with?"

Consider this conversation:

> "Who's the guy in this picture?"
> "That's Graham Taylor."
> "Who the heck is Graham Taylor?"
> "He's an English footballer."

You might argue that the second "who" question was really a "what" question. You might argue that it's the question the first speaker really intended from the start; you could imagine a more prescient second speaker answering a "who" question with a "what" answer.

To put a finer point on it, you could argue that "Who" is about *identity*. If a person's occupation, mission, or characteristics become integral to their identity, then you can reasonably answer "who" with such information rather than a name.

> "Who was that masked man?"
> "He's a Texas Ranger who devoted his life to frontier justice, and for some reason values his anonymity."
> "Thanks, that's what I was *really* asking!"

Comment: As in the famous Theoden quote from LOTR: "Who am I, Gamling?" It's rare that I upvote an answer that really belongs on a duplicate thread.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you, without a context, this kind of puzzles is meaningless as far as I see it. And I think this conversation "-What is he? -He is an English footballer." is rarely seen in real life, is it(I'm not a native speaker just my feeling)? Like your example, I prefer to use "Who" even if it's actually a "What" question. No matter what, thank you again.